# How to Calculate Frequency "X values" from a FFT/DFT Transformation

Tags: fft, sampling, frequency

First of all I am totally new to the DSP field and I have no background in it whatsoever, but my work in biology has led me to data that would greatly benefit from DSP.  Any answers devoid of specific DSP math notation, verbage or symbols would be greatly appreciated.

My question is: how do I calculate the frequency values or "X axis" values that go with the DFT peaks' "Y values" that were output from a DSP program?  I have used a program that output the following DFT and I can also access/print out the actual "Y values"/peak heights themselves, but not the "X values"/frequency values:

[image: FFT Output]

I have heard it mentioned that the sampling frequency/sampling rate and the number of data points that make up the above graph/plot are the only necessary ingredients needed to calculate the "X values" that go with the "Y values" (peak heights) but I don't know what this math equation/formula is.  I have also heard mention of something called "frequency bins" but I am not sure if that has any relevance to my question on this post (since the word "bin" reminds me of the bins mentioned in statistics for histograms, but those bins are ranges of values, not the discrete "X values" I am asking about here).  Any help/direction or hints would be greatly appreciated.

LM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have heard about the sampling frequency/rate and the number of samples/data points is correct. When you take $n$ samples in the *time-domain* representation of the signal and "Fourier Transform" them (I use the term loosely without getting into details about DFT, DTFT, FFT etc.) you end up with equal amount of samples ($n$ that is). Those samples now represent the "amplitude" (I also use this term quite loosely) of some frequencies.

Your data after the transformation to the *frequency-domain* will now contain all the frequency information from $0 Hz$ (DC that is) up to your sampling frequency/rate, which I will denote with $f_{s}$. The spacing of the frequencies on the $x$-axis is linear so the whole spectrum is divided into equal intervals. This interval, denoted here as $\Delta f$, is given by

$$\Delta f = \frac{f_{s}}{n}, ~~~~~~~~~~~~ n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots, N - 1 \tag{1}$$

where $N$ represents the number of samples used.

**Bins** is indeed the term (or at least one of the terms) used in this case. So, each interval is denoted as one bin. It has indeed direct connection to the term as used in statistics when creating histograms because in each bin is included the energy in the band

$$\left[n \Delta f - \frac{\Delta f}{2}, n \Delta f + \frac{\Delta f}{2}\right], ~~~~~~~~~~~~ n = 1, 1, 2, \ldots, N - 1 \tag{2}$$

where for $n = 0$ the bin corresponds to DC and is the mean of all the values.

One comment to make here is that, in case of a real-valued signal/function, the magnitude/spectrum will be an *even* function (the second half of the data is mirrored in respect to the *y*-axis) and the phase information an *odd* function (the second half of the data is mirrored in respect to the *y*-axis and negated in respect to the *x*-axis). Thus, for analysis, one could use only the first half of the data (or the second half if the first half represents negative frequencies, but this is implementation dependent).

Comment: Thanks for your kind response.  If I may then elaborate on my system: I have a total of 200 data points in the time domain but when I use the program's FFT feature, it returns a total of 129 points which constitute the transform's data points.  This program does not require me to provide a sampling frequency in order to obtain the transform.  Does the above sound normal as what software packages typically ask for in order to output transform data points?  Please correct me if I'm wrong but it sounds as if I should also have 200 transform data points in the frequency domain.  Thanks.

Comment: @LobsterMan123, I have skipped a lot of details in the answer and this may have hidden some things from you. The FFT works best when the number of the input data (the time-domain signal that is) is a power of 2. So, most probably the software you use, zero-pads (adds zeros) until the length of your signal vector is a power 2 and greater than the original signal (256 most probably in your case). Now, after zero-padding the length of the input to the FFT is 256 samples (some of them zeros as I said, which doesn't alter the included information somehow). As I mentioned in the answer (cont.)

Comment: (contd.) when the input to the transform is real-valued, half of the spectrum is the complex conjugate of the other half. This makes half the information redundant. So, the software "discards" (does not show) half the spectrum which is identical to the other half. This is why you get 129 bins (the last bin corresponds to the Nyquist frequency, which is equal to half your sampling frequency). Now, if your software does not know the sampling frequency then the values get on the x-axis correspond to bins without any information of frequency. You have to keep in mind that the transform (cont.)

Comment: (contd.) is an algorithm which can very well be performed without any knowledge of the frequency, it's just a mathematical formula implemented numerically on a computer. Nevertheless, this does not change the output of the transform, it just does not provide any information on the frequencies. For example, if your sampling frequency would be 10 Hz, then the whole [0 Hz, 5 Hz] frequency band would be divided into 129 bins. If it were 10 kHz then the band [0 Hz, 5 kHz] would be divided (linearly of course) to 129 bins. Hope that makes sense. Let us know if it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you for explaining all of this.  My follow-up question then is the following: is my sampling frequency the frequency with which I collected my original time domain data?  If so, I actually collected my data once per nanosecond for a total of 200 nanoseconds.  How do you recommend I "Hertzify" this data collection frequency (assuming this is indeed what is meant by a sampling frequency).  Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Yep, sampling frequency is (most often than not) the frequency with which you collect the data. Assuming no sampling rate conversion has happened (which is a reasonable assumption to make when you just acquire data and don't do any other specific processing) then your sampling period (the duration between two consecutive acquisitions) is $T_{s} = 1 ns$... The relation of period and frequency is $f_{s} = \frac{1}{T_{s}}$ so your sampling frequency is $f_{s} = \frac{1}{1 10^{-9} s} = 10^{9} Hz$. This implies that half this frequency range $\left[ 0, 5 \cdot 10^{8} \right]$ will (cont.)

Comment: be represented by the 129 bins provided by the transform, with the frequency spacing that corresponding to $\Delta f = \frac{f_{s}}{2 N}$.

Comment: Sounds good.  So in my specific case then, I went ahead and am considering my frequencies as MegaHertz and so I've done the following: 1) sampling rate is 1000 MHz, 2) divided 1000 MHz into 2 to get my range of [0, 500 MHz], 3) since I have 129 bins, divide 500 into 129 to get roughly 3.875.  So if the axis is zero, does this mean my first frequency data point's X-axis coordinate component will be 3.875 MHz and the second's will be 7.750 MHz and the third's will be 11.625 and so on? Or would each X-axis value be 1000 MHz/(2*200 data points)=2.5 per the last equation?  Thanks again.

Comment: The first sample/bin always corresponds to DC ($0$ Hz that is). Then the next corresponds to $0 + \Delta f$ Hz. So, according to your numbers, the first bin is your DC component and the first bin corresponds to $3.875$ MHz. Please note that the bins "indricate" the energy (or amplitude better termed) present in a frequency band and not just at the specific frequencies that the calculations indicate. Since the axis is linear, you can think of each bin as a frequency band of $\Delta f$ Hz with its centre frequency being the one calculated with the formula provided in the answer.

Comment: Sounds good.  Lastly, since these bins correspond to amplitudes, does this mean that the y-axis of the frequency plot (i.e. the output of the DFT) has the same units as whatever I collected in my raw data (i.e. if I collected angle values in degrees over time, the y-axis of the frequency plot will be in units of degrees too)?  Thanks again for answering my questions.